# For each positive integer $m$, find a polynomial $y(x)$ such that $xy''(x)+(1-x)y'(x)+my(x)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

> Show that, for every $m \in \mathbb{N}$, there is a polynomial $y(x)$ such that $$\bigg(xD^2+(1-x)D+m\bigg)y(x)=0$$

This is a past year exam question in my ODE module and my lecturer did not provide any solutions for this particular paper. I'd still like to know how can i go about proving this question at my own pace. I have completely no clue as to how to start this question so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure the leading coefficient isn't "$x^2$"?

Comment: Just to be sure, $\dfrac{d}{dx}$ is the derivative of $y(x)$ or do you mean $\dfrac{dy(x)}{dx}$ is the derivative of $y(x)$?

Comment: @Holo I think in this case it is equivalent to the differential operator $D$

Comment: @DMH16 so $(xD_x^2+...)$?

Comment: This seems to have as particular solution Laguerre polynomials which are of degree $m$.

Comment: There is _one_ polynomial $y$ that satisfies this relation _for all $m$_? Or for all $m$, there is a polynomial $y$... (where the $y$ can be different for different $m$)?

Comment: Context? Personal tries?

Comment: The zero polynomial seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

$\require{cancel}$
Hoping all my calculations are correct, this might be an answer:

Let: $$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_nx^{n+r},\quad y'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n(n+r)x^{n+r-1},\quad y''(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n(n+r)(n+r-1)x^{n+r-2}$$

Substituting in the original equation we obtain:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n(n+r)(n+r-1)x^{n+r-1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n(n+r)x^{n+r-1}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n(n+r)x^{n+r}+\\+\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_nm\cdot x^{n+r}=0$$
Factoring out $x^r$ and making the simple substitution $n=k+1$ for the first two sums and $n=k$ for the other two, we obtain:

$$x^r\left[\sum_{k=-1}^\infty C_{k+1}(k+r+1)(k+r)x^{k}+\sum_{k=-1}^\infty C_{k+1}(k+r+1)x^{k}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty C_k(k+r)x^{k}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty C_km\cdot x^{k}\right]=0$$
Evaluating the first two sums for $k=-1$ and putting them together, leads to:
$$(r^2-r)C_0x^{-1}+rC_0x^{-1}+\\+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left[C_{k+1}(k+r+1)(k+r)+C_{k+1}(k+r+1)-C_k(k+r)+mC_k\right]x^k=0$$ 
From the above equation we are able to obtain the indicial polynomial and the recurrence relation for $k=\{0,1,2,3...\}$:
$$ \begin{align*}
        (r^2-r)C_0x^{-1}+rC_0x^{-1}&= 0 &C_{k+1}(k+r+1)(k+r)+C_{k+1}(k+r+1)-C_k(k+r)+mC_k=0\\
r&= 0 &C_{k+1}=\frac{(k+r-m)C_k}{k^2+2rk+2k+r^2+r+1}
        \end{align*}$$
Subsituting $r$ in the recurrence relation, we obtain:
$$C_{k+1}=\frac{(k-m)C_k}{k^2+2k+1}$$
Evaluating for different values of $k$,
\begin{align}
\text{For } k=0:& \quad\quad C_1 =-mC_0\\
\text{For } k=1:& \quad\quad C_2 =\frac{1-m}4C_1\\
\text{For } k=2:& \quad\quad C_3 =\frac{2-m}9C_2=\frac{(2-m)(1-m)}{36}C_1\\
\text{For } k=3:& \quad\quad C_4 =\frac{3-m}{16}C_3=\frac{(3-m)(2-m)(1-m)}{576}C_1\\
\vdots
\end{align}
Therefore, knowing that:
$$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_nx^{n+r}$$
and with all the information obatined, $y(x)$ can be expressed as:
$$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_nx^{n}=C_0-mC_0x+\frac{1-m}4C_1x^2+\frac{(2-m)(1-m)}{36}C_1x^3+\frac{(3-m)(2-m)(1-m)}{576}C_1x^4+\cdots$$
Thus:
$$y_1(x)=C_0(1-mx)$$ $$ y_2(x)=C_1\left(\frac{1-m}4x^2+\frac{(2-m)(1-m)}{36}x^3+\frac{(3-m)(2-m)(1-m)}{576}x^4+\cdots\right)$$
As we can see from $y_2(x)$, if $m\in\mathbb{N}$ the differential equation will have as a solution a polynomial of degree $m$.

---

For instance, let $m=3$, then:
$$y(x)=C_0-3C_0x-\frac12C_1x^2+\frac1{18}C_1x^3+\cancel{0\cdot C_1x^4}+\cancel{0\cdot C_1x^5}+\cancel{0\cdot C_1x^6}\cdots$$
As you can see, the solution of the differential equation is a polynomial with highest degree equal to $3=m$.

Comment: No idea why you introduce a parameter $r$ at all...

Comment: @Did Because $x=0$ is a regular singular point

Comment: And? One is asked for a polynomial and every polynomial is $$y(x)=\sum_{k=0}^NC_kx^k$$

Comment: @Did I applied Frobenius method, in either case the solution is equivalent

Comment: Can we **think** just one minute instead of referring to keywords, and see that setting $r=0$ from the start (that is, forgetting about $r$) works fine?

Comment: @Did In general, you could have more than one solution for $r$ and not equal to zero. In this case, yes, it is only one and equal to zero. However, I did not know this until I found the indicial polynomial. Let me ask you a question, how could you be so sure that we only had one value for $r$ without solving the indicial polynomial? (Maybe there is a technique which I don’t know about). In either case, if it bothers you this much, you are free to edit my answer. However, since it is not wrong I don’t feel the need to take the parameter $r$ out.

Comment: Please let us leave aside crap notions such as "bothers you so much" and let us stay on mathematics, right? The (unique) point I am making (non ambiguously, from the start) is that setting $r=0$ (that is, forgetting about $r$), **one cannot miss any polynomial solution**. You might be confusing the present situation with cases where one searches for solutions $$y(x)=x^rz(x)$$ where $z(x)$ is a polynomial or an entire series, and $r\in(0,1)$. Here, one looks for **polynomial solutions** hence  introducing $r$ is definitely superfluous.

Comment: @Did yes that’s true

Comment: Rewrite, then? $ $

Comment: @Did tomorrow I will because now it’s very late

Comment: Sure, no problem.